# у меня игровой тг бот, хочу сделать код который будет выдавать число и после будет бездействующим ( одноразовый промокод

Tags: python, бот

это код в боте для получения бонуса, хочу понять как сделать такой, но одноразовый

```
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: message.text.lower() == 'бонус' or message.text == ' Бонус')
def bonus(message):
    baninf = cursor.execute(f"SELECT ban FROM users WHERE id = {message.chat.id}").fetchone()
    if baninf[0] == 0:
        usernick = cursor.execute(f'SELECT nick FROM users WHERE id = {message.chat.id}').fetchone()
        bonust = cursor.execute(f'SELECT bonus_last FROM users WHERE id = {message.chat.id}').fetchone()
        s = time.localtime(time.time())
        if bonust[0] != s.tm_sec:
            cursor.execute(f"UPDATE users SET money = money + ? WHERE id = {message.chat.id}", (cfg['bonus'],))
            cursor.execute(f"UPDATE users SET bonus_last = ? WHERE id = {message.chat.id}",
                           (time.localtime(time.time()).tm_sec,))
            db.commit()
                           f"{usernick[0]} Вы успешно получили бонус в размере {cfg['bonus']}$ {SMILE[5]}")
        else:
            bot.reply_to(message, f"{usernick[0]} Вы уже получали бонус {EMOJI_SAD[0]}")
```

Comment: Завести таблицу для промокодов, при получении кода от бота искать его в таблице, если есть - применять соответствующий бонус. После можно или удалить запись из таблицы, или добавить поле `activated_at` с датой активации (если нужно в дальнейшем)

Comment: спасибо, а если я хочу ограничить число активаций?

Comment: можно еще добавить в таблицу поле с количеством доступных активаций, и после активации уменьшать это число. Соответственно, при поиске промокода нужно учитывать, чтобы это число было больше 0